# warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct __sFILE *')

Tags: c, file, pointers, char, scanf

I am trying to execute my code but I seem to get this incompatible warning.

```
int Read_Data_File(void)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char *end = "0.0.0.0 none";
    char *buf;
    int endLoop = 0;

    ptr_file = fopen("CS222_Inet.txt", "r");


    if (!ptr_file) 
        return 1;

    int i = 0;

    while (!feof(ptr_file)){
        addr[i]=(struct address_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct address_t));
        fscanf(ptr_file,"%s",buf);
        if(!(strcmp(buf, end) == 0)){
            fscanf(buf,"%d %d %d %d %s", &addr[i]->IP1, &addr[i]->IP2,  &addr[i]->IP3, &addr[i]->IP4, addr[i]->name);
            n++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```

I want this program to read the file and also store my structure type into my buf pointer.

Warning Output:

```
project.c:65:11: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to
      parameter of type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct __sFILE *')
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                        fscanf(buf,"%d %d %d %d %s", &addr[i]->IP1, &add...
                               ^~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:250:30: note: 
      passing argument to parameter here
int      fscanf(FILE * __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...) __scanf...
                                 ^
```

Comment: It's telling you the error exactly: Your second `fscanf`'s first argument is `buf`, which is not a file. Also, Google "while (!feof()) is always wrong".

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says: `fscanf` expects its first argument to be a `FILE *`, whereas you're passing it a character buffer.
If you want to parse a character buffer using the `scanf` family of functions, use `sscanf`

Comment: I actually tried to sscanf, the output I got on the interface said bus error: 10. Which I also don't know what that means. Can you help me with that?

Comment: This is likely because you declared buf as a char pointer but didn't allocate any memory to it. Try making buf a char array or dynamically allocate some memory with malloc and make buf point to it (make sure it to free it properly afterwards)